# imageSource property is unavailable on Squish IDE?

Tags: qt, imagesource, squish

I would like to know if an image is green or red in a button I test with Squish.

My problem is that the imageSource property of my Qt object button is blank in Squish IDE so I don't know if it displays a green image or a red image.

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

It seems that if I don't have this property I can't test the color of my button with Squish since there isn't any other information in my Qt object to find out the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to pull it off !

I looked in SquishIDE and found the image which was in a child object in the Application Objects View. This object was unreachable with the picker, that's why it was hard to find it.
Then I just had to access the object with its real name.

Answer (score 1):

The imageSource property may be a QUrl (a "complex object"). The IDE does not always support "converting" that into a string representation, or expanding such a property shown in the "Variables" view.

But when you assign imageSource to a variable...

```
# Example quickcontrols2/wearable:
startApplication('wearable')

o = waitForObject({"container": {"type": "QQuickApplicationWindow"}, "id": "homeButton", "type": "NaviButton"})


# Look at "imageSource" in "Variables" view", it can
# be expanded now:
imageSource = o.imageSource


# Log "path" component of imageSource:
test.log("o.imageSource.path: %s" % o.imageSource.path)
```

...then you can expand and further inspect it in the "Variables" view.

But you can also [pick](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/howto/picking-inspecting-objects/) the object and then inspect the imageSource and its components in the "Application Objects" view, too.